# How would I name O-methylations on sugars while retaining the sugar’s common name?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbohydrates

Suppose I had a monosaccharide, e.g. D-arabinose. Suppose I do a few synthetic steps with it, and end up with the compound methyl (2*S*,3*R*,4*R*)-3,5-dihydroxy-2,4-dimethoxypentanoate. (as labelled by ChemDraw. If that is not the PIN, please correct.)

[image]

However, when writing my paper/thesis/lab report, I would love to derive the base name from D-arabinose for simplicity and consistency. The monosaccharide derivatives with a carboxylic acid in place of an aldehyde are *-onic acids* so my base name would be *methyl D-arabinonate*. But how would I correctly and unambiguously label the methoxy groups?

If I used 2,4-dimethyl, that would sound like this second compound:

[image]

And if I used 2,4-dimethoxy, wouldn’t that make it this one:

[image]

Is there a trick I am missing for clearly naming the compound as above with *methyl D-arabinonate* as a base name?

Comment: Did you have a look at *Pure Appl. Chem.*, **1996**, *68*, 1919-2008 [IUPAC](http://iupac.org/publications/pac/68/10/1919/)?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha No, because I didn’t know it existed ^^'

Comment: How about methyl 2O, 4O-dimethylarabinoate?

Comment: @CurtF. After skimming across Klaus’ source, yeah, something like that. If someone who had previous experience in doing so could answer, that would be great ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to name such compounds based on retained carbohydrate names in accordance with the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* as follows.

> **P-102.5.6** Monosaccharide derivatives
>
> **P-102.5.6.1** *O*-Substitution
>
> In order to maintain the integrity of structures and take advantage of retained names to imply the absolute configuration, *O*-substitution is allowed in carbohydrate nomenclature. Substituents replacing the hydrogen atom of an alcoholic hydroxy group of a monosaccharide or monosaccharide derivative are denoted as *O*-substituents. The substitution of an anomeric hydroxy group is discussed in P-102.5.6.3.2. The *O*-locant is not repeated for multiple substitution by the same atom or group. Number locants are used as necessary to specify the positions of substituents; they are not required for compounds fully substituted by identical atoms or groups.
>
> **P-102.5.6.1.1** *O*-Acetyl and *O*-alkyl functionalization.
>
> For *O*-acyl derivatives, names with the acid component cited as a separate word ending in ‘ate’ after the monosaccharide name are preferred to names using *O*-acyl group prefixes. However when the ose ending is changed (e.g. to denote a glycosyl or an acid function having seniority over an ester) *O*-acyl prefixes are required. *O*-Alkyl derivatives are always expressed by prefixes.

Therefore, the name for the corrsponding D-arabinose derivative with methyl substituents replacing the hydrogen atoms of two alcoholic hydroxy group is 2,4-di-*O*-methyl-D-arabinose.

[image: D-arabinose]    [image: 2,4-di-O-methyl-D-arabinose]